# Whitelabel Error Page, rest urls not executed in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

new to spring boot application development. I ran the application as java application and got the below error. THe application is deployed successfully , I don't know why this error is rendered ... beating my head.. thank you for your help in advance.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Sat Jul 13 21:37:31 IST
>   2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No
>   message available

tried solutions given on stack overflow but no help. could you please help me if anywhere I do wrong here.

```
package com.cpi.poc.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cpi.poc.service.IService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cgi.poc")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    IService service;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greet" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testService(){
        String result = service.greet();
        return result;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cgi.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: are you making request to `http://localhost:<port>/test/greet` ?

Comment: can you add code of main class with imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.cgi.poc")
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

No need to put component scan on controller if you have the above class.
Verify by using lsof command that your java service is running on the port on not.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I had missed the service and component annotation in service class.. this is what made me struggle to run the application..